# Not clear why the use effect hook gets triggered too many times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a timer with react

for some sort of reason, it is not incrementing properly - the use effect hook gets triggered too many times and I do know why is that happening

instead of incrementing in 1 second intervals it in increments 3 or more second intervals

Maybe you explain why the hook gets triggered so many times and what i could do to resolve the issue

````
const Timer = () => {
  const [timeDisplayed, setTimeDisplayed] = useState(0);
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(0)
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        var delta = Date.now() - startTime; 
  
        setTimeDisplayed(timeDisplayed + Math.floor(delta / 1000))

        
      }, 1000);
    } else if (!timerOn) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn, timeDisplayed]);


  const start = () => {
    setStartTime(Date.now())
    setTimerOn(true)
  }

  const stop = () => {
    setTimerOn(false)


  }


  const reset = () => {
    setTimerOn(false)
    setTimeDisplayed(0)

  }


  return (
    <div >
      <h2>Timer</h2>
   
        <p>{timeDisplayed}</p>
      <div id="buttons">
       <button disabled={timerOn} onClick={() => {start()}}>{timeDisplayed===0 ? 'Start' : 'Resume'}</button>
    
     <button disabled={!timerOn} onClick={() => stop()}>Stop</button>
      <button disabled={timeDisplayed === 0} onClick={() => reset()}>Reset</button>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;```
````

Comment: timeDisplayed is one of your dependencies so every time you call setTimeDisplayed the useEffect will trigger again

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue?  Make sure to mark the most correct answer, or provide more details if they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `timerOn` you start updating `timeDisplayed` every second, and because your effect specifies `timeDisplayed` as a dependency it runs again. `timerOn` is still true, so it calls `setInterval` again, and now you have it updating twice every second. Then three times. Four. And so on.

You could fix this by either 1) returning a cleanup function that clears the interval, or 2) setting `interval` back to null when the timer is off and adding it to your start condition:

```js
if (timerOn && !interval) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    var delta = Date.now() - startTime; 
    setTimeDisplayed(prev => prev + Math.floor(delta / 1000))
    }, 1000);
  } else if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
}, [timerOn, timeDisplayed]);
```

Comment: hey thanks - yes, solved by clearing the interval immediately 

solution that i used:

`  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        var delta = Date.now() - startTime;      
        setTimeDisplayed(Math.floor(delta / 1000))
   
        
      }, 1000);
    } else if (!timerOn) {
      
    }

  }, [timerOn, timeDisplayed]);`

Answer (score 0):

You `useEffect` is updating state that it is dependent on.  Meaning it calls itself recursively.

Make use of the callback function of your state setter `setTimeDisplayed`, and remove `timeDisplayed` from your dependency array.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let interval = null;

  if (timerOn) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      var delta = Date.now() - startTime; 
  
      setTimeDisplayed(prev => prev + Math.floor(delta / 1000))  
    }, 1000);

  } else if (!timerOn) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [timerOn]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is not with the useEffect hook. It's in the logic you are using to update value of timeDisplayed. You are adding previous value with new updated count.

****For example :****

when timeDisplayed = 1,  Math.floor(delta / 1000) returns 2. That's why on next update timeDisplayed'svalue is set to 3 (timeDisplayed + Math.floor(delta / 1000)) instead of 2.

Try adding a console.log statement as shown below to see all values at each update.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        var delta = Date.now() - startTime; 
        console.log('vals',timeDisplayed, Math.floor(delta / 1000),timeDisplayed + Math.floor(delta / 1000) )
        setTimeDisplayed(timeDisplayed + Math.floor(delta / 1000))        
      }, 1000);
    } else if (!timerOn) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn, timeDisplayed]);
```

Update you useEffect to this and your problem should be solved.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        var delta = Date.now() - startTime; 
        setTimeDisplayed(Math.floor(delta / 1000))        
      }, 1000);
    } else if (!timerOn) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn, timeDisplayed]);
```